# Существуют ли соглашения для комментариев сразу после залива проекта на гитхаб?

Tags: git, github

Прошу прощения еще раз, достаточно много сегодня я вопросов написал про гитхаб. Спасибо еще раз.

Допустим я заливаю готовый проект на гитхаб, а он ни разу не был на гитхабе, все файлы одним коммитом можно? Или каждый файл нужно по отдельности коммитить с разными комментариями?
К примеру когда вы устанавливаете django то в папке сразу появляются куча файлов от самой джанги. Или Ларавель.
Вы файлы наподобие route, view коммитите одним комментарием или нет?

Comment: Ну ты сам-то сотню файлов не устанешь коммитить по одному?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Значит можно чтобы все файлы имели один и тот комментарий от коммита? Да? Спасибо заранее

Comment: Коммиты нужны не для гитхаба, а для программистов, которые будут разбираться в истории проекта. Если коммит будет один — вся история сотрётся и будет затруднено разбирательство в проблемах. Если вы не делали коммиты в процессе разработки проекта — вы уже изначально облажались.

Comment: Понял спасибо. А что тогда в таком случае можно сделать? Уже ничего да? Ах да еще вопрос. А если к примеру ты только начал проект писать. И там готовые файла от фреймворка заработали, какой комментарий можно написать? К примеру в django файл urls, templates.

Comment: Коммиты нужно делить не по файлам, а по выполняемым действиям. «Создан пустой Django-проект» — это один коммит со всеми созданными файлами. «Добавлены модели и миграции» — это второй коммит с двумя-тремя файлами. «Исправлена опечатка в поле модели» — это третий коммит с исправлением в одной строке, и так далее по логике.

Comment: @andreymal оформите как ответ

Comment: Когда я создаю Django-проект с нуля, я делаю startproject/startapp, добавляю какую-то базовую пустую страничку с сообщением в стиле «Ура, это работает!», слегка поправляю settings.py на свой вкус и делаю из этого первый коммит с подписью «Initial commit». А уже после этого я начинаю добавлять модели, основные вьюхи, админку и всё остальное в отдельных коммитах. (Но нужно понимать, что это всё очень сильно субъективно, и мои предпочтения могут не совпадать с предпочтениями других пользователей)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо огромное. То что хотел. Еще раз большое спасибо. Буду знать теперь, как надо последовательно все дело делать. В интернете просто я не нашел.

Comment: @MoloF на мой взгляд это всё слишком субъективно, так что от ответа я на всякий случай воздержусь. Ещё в 2015-м я запихивал весь проект в один-единственный коммит, считая это более правильным и противореча сам себе :) Ещё я любил делать [такие коммиты](https://github.com/andreymal/ponyFiction/commit/cd12a518a898fea39e9d2cebc863d1ca4d897136)...)))

Comment: @MoloF кстати, вопрос по сути не имеет прямого отношения к Django, так что если уж и писать ответ, то в таком вопросе, формулировка которого будет канонической и отвязанной от конкретных технологий, чтобы можно было отмечать другие вопросы как дубликаты канонического

Comment: @andreymal убрал метку.

Answer (score 2):

Все файлы одним коммитом однозначно. Те файлы, которые заливать не хотите пропишите в `.gitignore`

Comment: Программисты, которые будут читать историю и git blame, захотят очень сильно побить автора этого одного коммита.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Значит можно чтобы все 100 файлов имели один комментарий да? И еще. А какой комментарий обычно пишут если полностью проект заливают?

Comment: Пишут что-то вроде `git commit -m "first commit"` или `"initial commit"`